# Python Return Outside Function Syntax Error

Tags: python

Hi I'm going through Google's Python Class  and I doing one of the exercises. Here is the exercise

```
# A. donuts
# Given an int count of a number of donuts, return a string
# of the form 'Number of donuts: <count>', where <count> is the number
# passed in. However, if the count is 10 or more, then use the word 'many'
# instead of the actual count.
# So donuts(5) returns 'Number of donuts: 5'
# and donuts(23) returns 'Number of donuts: many'
I have so far tried: 

def donuts(count):
    if count >= 10:
      print 'Number of donuts: many'
    else:
      print 'Number of donuts: %d' % (count)
return count
```

But so far I keep getting the syntax error above. Is there someone who can explain this?

Comment: btw, just to let you know, it ask for you to return a string, not print it, nor does it ask you to return a int (the `count` variable)

Comment: It's exactly as it says. The `return` is outside of the function. Why are you expecting it to be inside?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `return` is on the same indentation as the `def`. It should be like this:

```
def donuts(count):
    if count >= 10:
        print 'Number of donuts: many'
    else:
        print 'Number of donuts: %d' % (count) 
    return count
```

The `return` command is part of the function definition, so must be indented under the function introduction (which is `def donuts()`). If it weren't, there would be no way for the interpreter to know that the `return` statement wasn't just a part of your broader code.

However, as freeforall said, the question asks for a string to be returned, so the correct answer would look more like:

```
def donuts(count):
    if count >= 10:
        return 'Number of donuts: many'
    else:
        return 'Number of donuts: %d' % count
```